# Latest org.json

Tags: java, json

Where can I download the latest *org.json* JAR?

The API shows 2010/01/05 for `JSONObject` and my last download was 09/06/15. I can't find it on sourceforge or anywhere else.  Can someone direct to the latest that will have an API at least as specified as of 2010/01/05?

Answer (score 26):

As far as I can tell (in December 2013) ...

- Douglas Crockford's master source repository for "json.org" is now on GitHub - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java.  (The GIT history starts in 2010, and the latest change in "master" is a couple of weeks ago.)
- Paul Merlin (aka "eskatos") has Mavenized the code: https://github.com/eskatos/org.json-java
- Binary "org.json" JAR files are "regularly" built from Paul Merlin's tree and pushed to Maven Central.  You can find them via the "here" link in Paul's README.md file; see the line above.
- There are other older (pre-2010) binary releases of the "org.json" JAR file in Maven Central under various guises; review the search results for this link" http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=org.json.

The copyright dates in the "org.json" source code don't mean much.  They clearly aren't updated when the code is updated.  However, Douglas Crockford does update the `@version` javadoc tags, at least in some commits.

**UPDATE (December 2016)**

As of some time in 2015, Douglas Crockford has passed ownership of the Github repository to Sean Leary.  The old Github URL for the project now redirects to https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java.  The project continues to be relatively active.

See also: [Where has json.org java library gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519204/where-has-json-org-java-library-gone/35519355)

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) or one of the other JSON libraries for Java that have developed.  This has features the JSON.org API lacks (and I think it will stay that way).

For instance, the json-simple version of [JSONObject](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java) implements Map and [JSONArray](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java) implements List.  It also has other features, like a [SAX-style API](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_5_-_Stoppable_SAX-like_content_handler).

Comment: Thanks Matthew
I didnt realize it was that advanced.  I just want to get it done and explore better more current implementation later.  What is great is that community will keep the backward compatibility.

Comment: I noticed that json-simple doesnt have all the API's as JSON.org either - e.g. XML.java

Comment: @RajeevM, no, it's not the same.  But last time I checked, it was better in some ways (see second paragraph).

Comment: Links to JSONArray and JSONObject are dead.

Comment: You're giving an opinion, not answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

org.json is now regularly updated in the Maven repository. The latest release is 12 Feb, 2016: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json.

Github location for the code: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Can you tell us how to make the download (the zip file or the github clone) available in eclipse.  The package has the source files, but there isn't content to import into an Eclipse project.  I used the commanline to compile the source files into class files.  However, I still couldn't succeed in adding the libraries to my Eclipse project.  Can you help?