# Where has json.org java library gone?

Tags: java, json

So, I'm trying to learn JSON, for Java, but it appears to be a moving target - there are a number of libraries available, but I prefer to stick to either the JSON.ORG version or the Oracle Java javax version. 
However, it seems that JSON.ORG no longer provides docs or an 'official' library.  None of the .org links I have found - apart from the landing page - work any longer.
E.g.  http://www.json.org/java

The end result is that much of what I find and learn I can't apply because they reference the JSON.ORG library which does not seem to be available any longer.

The landing page does provide a list of *other* libraries that can be used.  One of these is generically named: JSON-lib on sourceforge.  Is this the one that used to be on JSON.ORG?  There's no reference that says that.

Am I missing something?  Is the JSON.ORG library available elsewhere, or shuld I just stick with Oracle's javax.json?  Or, is Google's version a better option?

Comment: Google's GSON library is very fast and has really useful helper utilities.  I have replaced the formal json.org (which you can still find maintained by Sean Leary at https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java Douglas Crockford contributes to this project, https://github.com/douglascrockford)

Comment: @Jason Thanks.  Do you know if Google's GSON library the same as what is used in Android development?

Comment: A stable API is one of Java's core design principles.  Every public class, public field, and public method in the javax.json package is permanent and will never change (though new ones may be added).  I'd favor a java or javax package if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 4):

The org.json library originally written by Douglas Crockford is alive and well, and can be found here: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Jar files are available from the Maven repository: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json%22